# Need to replace words in a file with its line & position numbers

Tags: text-processing

I need to replace words in a file with its line & position numbers:

file1 has:

```
ABC XYZ UIO WER GFH
DFG JHKS
WEQ RWT DSW
ANSN WERER WERT QAZX UWRE AA
```

Need to replace its contents as follows:

```
S_11 S_12 S_13 S_14 S_15
S_21 S_22
S_31 S_32 S_33
S_41 S_42 S_43 S_44 S_45 S_46
```

The words will not repeat. Each file may have different sets and number of words.

Answer (score 3):

Another `perl`-based approach:

```
perl -pe 'my $i; s{\S+}{"S_$." . ++$i}ge'
```

That replaces every sequence of non-ASCII-whitespace characters in each line with the `S_<line-number><word-number>`, preserving the existing white space.

If the input may contain non-ASCII white space characters such as:

U+0085 NEXT LINE
U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+2000 EN QUAD
U+2001 EM QUAD
U+2002 EN SPACE
U+2003 EM SPACE
U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+2009 THIN SPACE
U+200A HAIR SPACE
U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

And they are encoded as per the user's locale, you can add the `-Mopen=locale` option.

You may or may not want to exclude the "no-break" space ones (U+00A0, U+2007 and U+202F above) though since they're not meant to be treated as separators. `perl` and PCRE (with `(*UCP)`) include them, GNU locales `[:space:]` `CTYPE` category doesn't. On my system, I find that U+0085 is not included in the locale's `[:space:]` and PCRE also includes U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR (which [used to be classified as whitespace in Unicode but no longer is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#MVS)). In `perl` see also `\PZ` for characters *not* (capital `p`) classified as separator and `\P{Zs}` for characters *not* classified as space separator (control characters including TAB are not considered as separators). I find that `\p{Zs}` is a subset of `\pZ` itself a subset of `\s`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -lane '$i=1; print join(" ", map { "S_$." . $i++ } @F)' file1
S_11 S_12 S_13 S_14 S_15
S_21 S_22
S_31 S_32 S_33
S_41 S_42 S_43 S_44 S_45 S_46
```

- `-l` automatically handle line-endings
- `-a` auto-split input line into an array called @F
- `-n` loop over each line of input without printing anything, similar to `sed -n`.
- `-e` the next argument is the script to execute.

Each line is automatically split (on whitespace) into the `@F` array (similar to how `awk` auto-splits each input line into $1, $2, ..., $NF).

The script resets `$i` to 1 at the start of each input line.

The `map` function returns a list of strings made up of the literal string `S_`, the line number (`$.`) and the variable `$i` (the `++` increments $i each time it is used), with the list having one element for each element in @F.

Each element of that list is then joined by spaces and printed.

Output will go to stdout.  If you want the input file to be changed instead, add the `-i` option between `perl` and the `-l`.  Or `-i.bak` if you also want the original file backed up before it is over-written.

---

BTW, because there is no delimiter between the line number ($.) and the word counter ($i) in the output, it is impossible to distinguish between, say, the eleventh word of the first line ("S_111") and the first word of the eleventh line (also "S_111").  I recommend adding a delimiter (say, `.` or another `_`) between those two values.  And, maybe zero-padding the numbers so they always have the same number of digits.  For example, using the `sprintf()` function inside `map`:

```
$ perl -lane '$i=1; print join(" ", map { sprintf "S_%03i.%03i", $., $i++ } @F)' file1
S_001.001 S_001.002 S_001.003 S_001.004 S_001.005
S_002.001 S_002.002
S_003.001 S_003.002 S_003.003
S_004.001 S_004.002 S_004.003 S_004.004 S_004.005 S_004.006
```

Answer (score 2):

How will you know given output like `S_1234` if it means the 34th column of the 12th line or 4th column of the 123rd line or something else? Not using a separator like `_` between the line and column numbers in  the output seems like a bad idea for whatever you're going to do with this data next.

This will do what you asked for:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i="S_" NR i} 1' file
S_11 S_12 S_13 S_14 S_15
S_21 S_22
S_31 S_32 S_33
S_41 S_42 S_43 S_44 S_45 S_46
```

but consider this instead:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i="S_" NR "_" i} 1' file
S_1_1 S_1_2 S_1_3 S_1_4 S_1_5
S_2_1 S_2_2
S_3_1 S_3_2 S_3_3
S_4_1 S_4_2 S_4_3 S_4_4 S_4_5 S_4_6
```

so you can robustly tell line from column numbers in the output by their stand-alone values.

The above will remove any lead/trailing white space from each line and convert all chains of contiguous whit space to single blank chars. I doubt if that's a problem but let us know if it is.

Comment: For all we know, the OP's input may be guaranteed to have fewer than 10 words per line in which case that `S_<line-number><word-number>` would be good enough. Note that it doesn't touch the white spaces in lines that have no word.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas right but they didn't say that so the issue is worth pointing out to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```bash
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){ printf "S_"NR i " " } print ""  }' file1 > newfile
mv newfile file1
```

Or if you are using `gawk` (in Linux `awk` is usually linked to `gawk`):

```bash
gawk -i inplace '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){ printf "S_"NR i " " } print ""  }' file1
```

The `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)` in awk is used to loop over the total of columns per line. `NF` stores the current column count per line.
And about the `printf "S_"NR i " "` in awk, using the `NR` I'm getting the number of the current line and the `i` is used for getting the current column index.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot Edgar!

Comment: @TexGC glad this worked for you. And I think there are simpler ways to achieve that.

Comment: Can you please explain `$_` in awk ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot that's not `$_`, it's a literal string `S_` (letter ess, not symbol dollar). Thankfully there is no `$_` in awk, unless someone is perverse enough to manually introduce such a variable.

Comment: That will add a blank to the end of every output line which is probably undesirable.

Comment: @EdMorton, `$_` is the `$` operator applied to the `_` variable. With `_` undefined or set to 0, that's the same as `$0`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know that's what it WOULD be but that's not part of the code being commented on, I think Gilles just misread `S_` as `$_` otherwise their request for an explanation of `$_` is just randomly pulled out of thin air.